# Is netbook RAM smaller than laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, netbook

I want to upgrade my netbook's RAM and my question is about its size. Can I use the RAM from my laptop?

Answer (score 8):

To my knowledge all netbooks on the market use the same physical size module as laptops. You need to check your documentation though to ensure you get the right type: DDR2 and DDR3 modules are not compatible and you need to make sure you don't buy a module that is larger than your machines chipset will take. Also make sure your netbook it actually easily upgradable: the Acer AA1s (at least the early models) are upgradable but you have to practically take apart the whole machine to get to the spare slot (see [this video to see how much hassle the procedure is](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3WVb1dL--o)). Many netbooks are much easier to upgrade though: the space RAM slot is often exposed under a panel on the underside and you only have to remove one screw to get in.

**Edit:** You will find several variations in speed available. Some old chipsets where very fussy and would not work correctly with mismatched speeds, but I'm not aware of anything made in the last decade or more that is so picky (the machine I had that was irritating in this way was, all those years ago, a 386 based box that didn't like 60ns and 70ns SIMMS being mixed). Your machine will detect the capability of the memory modules and run them all at the speed of the slowest, so make sure you get something as fast or faster than you already have. If you want to make doubly sure, either try match your existing module exactly or check the official specs which may state that speeds from X to Y are supported (i.e. have been tested).

Comment: +1, and my two cents: Nothing bad will happen anyway if you get the RAM bigger than is supported by the chipset. I will be just not used, and in result you will waste some bucks.

Comment: Hey there, thanks! I noticed on seller's pages that they have different Mhz. How this affect my netbook?

Comment: I would add.. the size of these laptop modules(including netbooks which i'd say are small laptops aka ultraportable laptops), is referred to as SO-DIMM. As opppose to DIMM.. SO-DIMM DDR modules as oppose to DIMM DDR modules.

Comment: @Halloumi: I've added a note about speed to the answer,

Comment: @Andrejs: I've seen at one motherboard completely refuse to work with a perfectly good 2Gb module, so while you might be right in general it is better to play safe and stick to the manufacturer's stated limits.

Answer (score 4):

Laptop and netbook RAM are pretty much the same size . However you do have to remember there are still different types of laptop/netbook RAM: DDR, DDR2, DDR3 all with different a number of pins. If you have the same type of laptop/netbook RAM you should be just fine.

Comment: My netbook has 1gb ram. Is there any problem if i upgrade it to 4gb ?

Comment: @Halloumi There shouldn't be a problem however some Motherboards have limitations on the amount of RAM you can have. For example my HP mini can only have 2GB even though I can put a 4gb stick in it. Let me know what kind of netbook you have and I'll look it up for you.

Comment: It is not a famous brand. It's called Turbo-X

Comment: What about the MHZ of ram? Should I care about ?

Comment: Yes! Check the FSB speed in your netbook specs, and go for the same speed on memory. I.e. DDR2-800Mhz or DDR2-666Mhz. But it's not critical, worst scenario - netbook will be slower.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the max support memory would be without a manual. You should be safe with 2 but you will be taking a chance with 4, let me know how it goes if you decide to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are the same. Only the number of slots may differ (netbooks have less slots; usually 1).

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com) website and use their memory identification tool to see what type of memory your systems require and see if they are the same.